# Schedule reboot in the background during debian preseeding

Tags: debian, preseed

I want to schedule a 30-minute reboot timer inside a Debian preseed so that in case of download problems etc. the installation does not hang (requiring someone on-site to reboot the machine manually).

I am installing from a netboot image.

The following does not work (it does not run in the background, but in the foreground):

```
d-i preseed/early_command string reboot -d 1800 &
```

```
d-i preseed/early_command string sh -c 'reboot -d 1800 &' ;
```

I think the culprit is the `log-output` program used here https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/preseed/-/blob/master/preseed_command#L16

Is there an alternative way to accomplish the scheduled reboot? Bonus if I do not have to install additional software (again, network problems …)

Comment: `nohup` might be your friend. Also, I don't know which state the machine is in during preseed, but transient systemd timers would be the cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

I realized that `screen` is available in the installer environment for Debian (it is *not* available in Ubuntu).  Therefore, you can use preseed configuration similar to this snippet.

```
d-i preseed/early_command string \
  screen -dmS reboot /sbin/reboot -d 60
```

**original post**

After digging into this I think to do exactly what you want that you need to write a daemon that properly backgrounds itself and executes `/sbin/reboot`.  You could use `early_command` to download and run the compiled daemon.

I started by testing the following preseed snippet.  It works the way you want in Ubuntu 20.04, but does *not* work in Debian Buster (as you experienced).

```
d-i preseed/early_command string \
  /sbin/reboot -d 60 &
```

Testing in a shell in both installers shows `log-output` is the reason Debian behaves differently.

I found that `log-output.c` was [patched](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer-utils/commit/log-output.c) to handle "in case the subsidiary process starts a daemon which does not fully disconnect its standard file descriptors".  While Ubuntu still has this patch, Debian [reverted it](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer-utils/-/commits/master/log-output.c) due to a bug it caused.

The installer environment is very minimal.  It does not have `nohup`, `screen`, or `start-stop-daemon` available as alternative ways to background a process.  Therefore, I think you would need an executable that can background itself properly and run the commands you want.

Links

- [Debian log-output.c](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer-utils/-/blob/master/log-output.c)
- [Ubuntu log-output.c](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer-utils/tree/log-output.c)
- [Ubuntu bug report that led to the patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1021293)
- [Debian bug report that led to Debian reverting patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=739989)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux